# Typescript is it possible to use a similar object as key inside a map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have a map with a key as object with a value as another map like this: `Map<CombinationValue, Map<CombinationValue, string>>`. This itself does not cause any errors but when I try to use set, has or get it won't recognize any of the key objects (so it won't retrieve an existing value or update based on the object key). Was wondering if there is a solution to this problem. Since I need to keep the objects still and can't replace it by just a id, since I need the object later on in the code. (I have to be able to use these operations on similar objects)

Here is a example of the code that I use [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIFdgBNQHMAyoEAzgMID2AtgEahxjDkgA8AKgHzIDeAUMv8hhQqALmSsA3HwFhyYyTwC+PHmACeABxQAFOMCjMAggBpkAIU4BeboP3EwYk8mIQETLGLPJFUnggA2cMTEyPjkCPSMIBQ0dAxM3NL82GL2UHhSAsggcJQQqWDpILi+WW4gaegIslAAFP7hkUwxtDnxIGJcyCnOhXimOXkFRbjeAJSJWVlgABbAxAB02MjWDRHtLXFRS1iZU-yz8wuDKKuNG1StTSDHuRB7-MrKfkz2yMLokMSOUFBwasxdPpmBhsHhCCASJs2lFmGF1lFodd2KY0nh2FZkABtJI2GB2Bx44SUMSQgDuoXOiMuWyYtS4PQARBo4FAANaMgZ3MTM1kcxQTUyyUkQCnw65I9r0pkAZk52W5yEZcoF3lRrncYgA5KwSGBkFh6HAtWrcV18VB7J1BMSRWKqc0aTC6QyPEqWez5SceR7+YLkMLsqLKQjHbFnSBpW7GQAmL2K2OM1WKdXlN06vUGo0mlNm2yWwnm21B+2h6JO65RnlyrlDJUq-2B8khiUVqWun18+N13me5OpzXIDNvQ1gY2mrLmgnWoSiEsti7hysd+vd-Kr1VCuTz8WLq7tplx2vrxP95wakDp3Uj7MTgRTgsz4vN3fUpcH6NHhU9uObgPbl8HXLd8oird0u2PTs+wmFNzzTbVr31Udx1zSd8ytIk50AstJVAldE0gpVf0bADg1fMN9zw2U12rJMYIHS8EMzZCc2MHgAF1fHKN5Z0oABZOANDEASNDhIDcKYUwRLEnC2yiVE+mKDEVnnESpBgcgoGQWpuP1D5IGQcgYHechPhICZeDKV59VkEThMEmTWxAyTehGTFeJEhZcAgMBan0iAFgtexAuJCYAH4wtUwSHn-TyXF8-zAoJBZZFMRKXDTMYYo8wSFnivzTMgJKCxCqgtxErKlBUbjyH8AKGlwWoco0BYZiCMDew5QjOroyqarqhYGqa4lPO83z8N9GjwOgvrXlq+ryEa5q8uAAAvCAsuQAB6LbnBmUz-CwZBqBQGVjs+bJyGQdANFHFBZHINlkA0QIkB4IA)

Also if it is not possible with a map is there another way to get the same result.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] with full, but minimal, code demonstrating the problem, in the question itself (and optionally, with a link to the same code in [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)). It's perfectly fine to use an object as a key in a `Map`, TypeScript just overlays types on it, it doesn't affect the functionality of the `Map`.

Comment: It's important to understand that `Map` uses **the object's identity** when comparing with keys, not *equivalance*. Two different objects are never the same key.

Comment: Objects in JavaScript are only equal if they are references to the same exact object; that is, `{a: 1} === {a: 1}` is `false`, as they are two different objects.  So presumably you are not passing the same object in as key twice.  Without a [mre] though it's hard to say how to proceed; you might want to hold onto a list of object keys, or just have the map keys be some serialized version of your objects

Comment: Here's an example showing a `Map` using objects similar to yours as keys without trouble, and demonstrating how two *different* equivalent objects are *different* keys: https://tsplay.dev/mMXVQN

Comment: @jcalz I have added a example but it is indeed a different object with similar values